# Утечка памяти при использовании SDL_Quit?

Tags: sdl

Имеется простейший код для создания окна при помощи `sdl2`:

```
::SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
auto window_ = ::SDL_CreateWindow("", 0, 0, 640, 480, ::SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

bool game_on = true;

while (game_on) {
  ::SDL_Event event;
  while (::SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
    switch (event.type) {
    case SDL_QUIT:
      game_on = false;
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }
  }
}

::SDL_Quit();
```

При этом после закрытия окна `address-sanitizer` указывает на утечку памяти:

```
==10545==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 8192 byte(s) in 2 object(s) allocated from:
  #0 0x4e1838 in __interceptor_malloc (/home/andrej/Public/git/sdl_game/bin/sdl_game+0x4e1838)
  #1 0x7f3eb1a61faf  (<unknown module>)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 8192 byte(s) leaked in 2 allocation(s).
```

Но если закомментировать последнюю строчку (::SDL_Quit()), то утечки памяти не происходит... Хотя по логике должно быть ровно наоборот - почему так?

Comment: А если сделать SDL_Init & SDL_Quit второй раз, утекает столько же, или в два раза больше?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat все то же количество байт

Comment: Тогда это не так плохо... Может зарепортить как баг?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat странно увидеть баг в одной из самых используемых функциях sdl..